# Код для проверки инпута

Tags: html, jquery, json, веб-программирование

Подскажите где может быть ошибка в коде? При проверке на количество символов и соответствие мобильным операторам, кнопка `submit` должна быть блокирована , но этого не происходит . Подскажите может чего не заметил?

вот код :

```js
     (function($) {


       var checkMobileOperator = function() {


         //var operators  = window.operators;
         var operators = [{
           code: '909',
           'name': 'Beeline'
         }, {
           code: '921',
           name: 'MTS'
         }];
         console.log(operators[0])

         this.check = function(value) {


           value = value.replace(/(?:^(7|\+7|8))*(?:\(|\))/g, '');


           if (value.length == 9) {


             var code = value.substr(0, 3);

             for (var i = 0, len = operators.length; i < len; i++) {
               if (operators[i].code === code)
                 return operators[i].name;
             }

             return null;
           }

         }

       }

       var CheckMobileOperator = new checkMobileOperator();

       var form = $('form'),
         input = $('#phone', form),
         submit = form.find('button["type=submit"]')
       submit.attr('disabled', 'disabled');

       console.log(input)

       input.on('keydown', function(e) {

         if (!((which >= 48 && which <= 57) || which == 13)) {
           e.preventDefault();
           return false;

         }



         !!checkMobileOperator.check(input.val()) && submit.removeAttr('disabled');

       });
     })(jQuery)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" autocomplete="off">
  <input id="phone" type="text" autocomplete="off" class="telephone" value="Введите Ваш номер" name="input">
  <div class="nambers">
    <button id="0" class="0 btn">0</button>
    <button id="1" class="1 btn">1</button>
    <button id="2" class="2 btn">2</button>
    <button id="3" class="3 btn">3</button>
    <button id="4" class="4 btn">4</button>
    <button id="5" class="5 btn">5</button>
    <button id="6" class="6 btn">6</button>
    <button id="7" class="7 btn">7</button>
    <button id="8" class="8 btn">8</button>
    <button id="9" class="9 btn">9</button>
    <button id="10" class="l0 btn">10</button>
    <button id="enter" class="entr btn" type="submit">Enter</button>
    <button id="backspace" class="backspace btn">backspace</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Попробуй замени submit = form.find('button["type=submit"]') на submit = form.find('#enter') или submit = $("'#enter");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас ошибка в селекторе кнопки отправки. Верно будет вот так:

```
submit = form.find('button[type=submit]');
```

Но еще можно сразу указать атрибут disabled у кнопки в верстке.
Так же рекомендуется использовать метод`.prop()` вместо `.attr()`

```
submit.prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: все сделал как вы и сказали, но почему-то не отрабатывает    вот пример кода: http://jsfiddle.net/t52ka/27/

Comment: P.S функция prop поддерживается в JQuery начиная с версии  1.6

Comment: Вообще это правильный ответ. Но по моему вопрошающему было бы гораздо полезнее рассказать про дебаг JS кода в FireBug или где-то еще. Иначе в следующий раз опять будут вопросы, а так он бы сам смог всё решить.

Comment: @Valeriy1996 выберете onLoad в JSfiddle